# An attack? What are the second status codes(286, 289) for in the log (a web scan)?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, http, httpd

Going through my assess-logs today, I found so many entries trying to access pages. (that were not present). Like

> - robots.txt (*I know what this is used for*)
> - apply
> - favicon.ico(*I know what this is used for*)
> - etc

So, obviously a `404` was returned but there was other 3 digit code(?) along with 404.

```
ip-address - - [date & time] "GET /some/file_OR_folder HTTP/1.1" 404 312
ip-address - - [date & time] "GET /some/file_OR_folder HTTP/1.1" 404 285
ip-address - - [date & time] "GET /some/file_OR_folder HTTP/1.1" 404 286
ip-address - - [date & time] "GET /some/file_OR_folder HTTP/1.1" 404 287
ip-address - - [date & time] "GET /some/file_OR_folder HTTP/1.1" 404 288
ip-address - - [date & time] "GET /some/file_OR_folder HTTP/1.1" 404 289
ip-address - - [date & time] "GET /some/file_OR_folder HTTP/1.1" 404 290
ip-address - - [date & time] "GET /some/file_OR_folder HTTP/1.1" 404 295
ip-address - - [date & time] "GET /some/file_OR_folder HTTP/1.1" 404 296
ip-address - - [date & time] "GET /some/file_OR_folder HTTP/1.1" 404 297
ip-address - - [date & time] "GET /some/file_OR_folder HTTP/1.1" 404 298
ip-address - - [date & time] "GET /some/file_OR_folder HTTP/1.1" 404 301
```

A search gave me this: [Samples of attacks detected by ossec - OSSEC Wiki](http://www.ossec.net/wiki/Samples_of_attacks_detected_by_ossec):
Which says it was `a web scan detected by ossec (looking for Wordpress, xmlrpc and awstats)` .

*What the second status codes(286, 289) for in the above log?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They aren't status codes, they're the response length in bytes.

Comment: Thanks. If every request(from same ip) I saw was a 404 , then the same error page should be delivered back why is the change in the length?

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey Headers

Comment: @ChrisS hmmm... gotta go through http headers a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisS that is the length of the reply without the header. The length of the requested filename makes the difference.